# Rounding an Int after shift division Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I need to be able to round an integer after shift division and I can't use `mul` or `div` instructions.

Example:

```
eax = 745

shr  eax, 3
```

This should give me the value 93 because it truncates the remainder. But say the float value was 749, using the `shr` instruction would still give me the value 93 even though it would normally be rounded to 94 (school grading).

How would I go about dealing with this problem?

All I can use for division and multiplication is `shr`/`shl`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part that is shift out is the remainder. For proper rounding you will need only the last bit of it and it remains in CF:

```
    shr   eax, 3    ; div by 8, the last shifted bit is in the CF
    adc   eax, 0    ; if CF=1 eax will be increased by 1
```

How it works? When dividing by shifting, the remainder is contained in the bits that are shifted out:

```
745 = $2e9 = 001011101001
749 = $2ed = 001011101101
```

When shifting it right, the lowest 3 bits will be shifted out. Notice that only the last shifted bit will remain in CF (pointed by "^") and it is the highest bit of the remainder:

```
001011101001 shl 3 = 0000 0101 1101|001 = $05d|1 = 93 and remainder 1 (0 in CF)
                                    ^

001011101101 shl 3 = 0000 0101 1101|101 = $05d|5 = 93 and remainder 5 (1 in CF)
                                    ^
```

For all possible remainders (0..111), these with 0 in the highest order bit are 000, 001, 010 and 011 (0..3) and these with 1 in the higher bit are 100, 101, 110 and 111 (4..7).

So, only the second example will be rounded up.

Comment: All that would accomplish is rounding the odds as opposed to the evens, it isn't checking the remainder to see whether the value is above .49

Comment: @BKreger - No, it will round properly. I will edit the answer in order to clean the explanation.

Comment: @BKreger The answer is edited with some explanation.